# adding intents to item in searchable listView

Tags: android, listview, android-intent

I'm a beginner. I'm developing an app with more activities in it. I have a listView in my MainActivity and searchView in the toolBar. Now I need to open other activities by searching the listView and clicking the items in the listView.
Help me..

```
ArrayList<String> arrayCountry = new ArrayList<>();
        arrayCountry.addAll(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_country)));

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(
                MainActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                arrayCountry);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String arrayCountry = lv.getAdapter().toString();

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you have been looking for,

```
Object GetLabel = lv.getItemAtPosition(position);
                        if (GetLabel.toString().equals("label1")) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, label1.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just put the intent in your itemClickListener.

```
onItemClick() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, <ACTIVITY_NAME>.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

I'm not sure if that's exactly what you're looking for since your description is kind of vague but this will start a new activity with no problems.

Comment: The code you have sent will launch <ACTIVITY_NAME>.class... But I want to launch other activities with respect to the items in the listView... sorry for my vague question... can u help me to modify my question?